# Control an activity from another class

Tags: android, controls, android-activity

I have two class, A and B. Class A display data from database in textview. Class B has a button, when click this button data of class B will radom change. Is it posible?

Comment: It is possible, add Activity object in the constructor of the class from where you want to control the activity something like `ClassB(Activity activityA, OtherArguments args)`

Comment: Are you even talking about an Android app? 
You should be working from Activities, and you can put both the button and the textviews in the same layout & Activity.

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski  No, no, no, no, no.  There are very rare circunstances when it's OK to pass an Activity context outside of it's own scope.  This is not one of them.  Bad practice.

Comment: You could create an Interface.  Have both activities implement it.  Use a callback to indicate that data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the data in the database and update it in the `onResume` method of your `Activity` displaying the `TextView`. Or you can use a static variable that stores the text in the `TextView` and modify it from the other class. Then you can update the text again in `onResume`.

You can't really access the `TextView` from another activity while it is not active.